# How do i get voicemail message programmatically in android?

Tags: android

i want to retrive a voicemail message in my android application.is there any way to do this?
or an API??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here, nobody is there to code a script for you. When you face a problem, first do some research (use google, search this site itself, etc.) Then you'll definitely come to a general idea of what your problem might be. Now apply your research in your work. See if it works or not. If there is no luck, do not hesitate to ask your question here. Programmers from all around the world will be more than happy to guide you further. (You will be able to show them what you have done so far by then) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

voicemail is accessed by dialing a number, to do this you have to all steps programatically.

May be you want to look at Google voice mail, i heart that they have their own service which provide voicemail service.

http://support.google.com/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115073

Comment: What about "visual voicemail" as initially offered on iPhone with some carriers?

Comment: I havent heard "visual voicemail" for android.